# Lowest empty position in Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a problem for you
I have a matrix of object. In object class I have a parameter X and Y (so i can get a list of X and list of Y).

In my code, I want to create a new object with the lowest position possible ([1;0]<[1;1]<[2;0]<...)

I try to do an algorithm for this but.. it's not so easy !

I'm coding in JAVA but all good reasoning is accept :p

EDIT :

Example : 
I have 4 objets

```
Obj1{X=1; Y=1}
Obj2{X=2; Y=2}
Obj3{X=3; Y=3}
Obj4{X=4; Y=4}
```

It's a diagonal Matrix 4 by 4
And the lowest position for a new object is X=1, Y=2

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input and expected output? The problem isn't entirely clear.

Comment: So you want to sort your objects by X and all obejcts with the same X shall be sorted by Y ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: So by "lowest" position, is `(0,9)` lower than `(1,0)`? ie. are you reading each row of the matrix left-to-right, like a book?

Comment: Exactly 
In my program I have a 2 dim matrix and i put this one on a 1 dim array